# Calling a Stored Procedure with a button on a form in Access - RUN-TIME Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I am using the following code to simply execute a Stored Procedure by clicking a button on an MS Access Form. However, this code produces the following error:
Run-time error '-2147217911 (80040e09)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SQL_Writeback', database 'Regulatory', schema 'dbo' Does anyone have some insight?

```
 Private Sub Image_RefreshButton_Click()

 Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
 Dim strSQL As String

 ' Instantiate the connection object
 Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

 ' Open the connection based on the strConnect connect string arguments
     With cnn
         .ConnectionString = cSQLConn
         .Open
End With

 ' Instantiate the command object
 Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

 ' Assign the connection and set applicable properties
 cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
 cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SQL_WriteBack"
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc


 ' Instantiate the recordset object by using the return value
 ' of the command's Execute method. Supply the parameters by
 ' packing them into a variant array
 Set rst = cmd.Execute()

 MsgBox "All manual entries had been updated."

 Set rst = Nothing
 Set cnn = Nothing
 Set cmd = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what db user are  you logging to as in your cSQLConn string?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Private Const cSQLConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbs####;UID=M01;PWD=M02;DATABASE=Regulatory;" That String works on other modules as well.

Comment: OK so does user "M01" have execute rights on the SP you are calling in the dbo schema?  My guess is, no.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Good Question, let me find out, I would be so inclined to think that you are right.

Comment: Put M01 in the db_owner group for giggles.  If it works, it is a permission issue.  Remove from db_owner group and GRANT rights at object level.  EXECUTE is what you want on a STORED PROCEDURE.

Comment: @Crafty DBA I did change the Permission to db_owner and it worked. However, I have not done the later part of your statement for fear of screwing something up. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Check out this MSDN link.  It tells you how to GRANT EXECUTE for a stored procedure.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx

```
-- Use sample database
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO

-- Give user [Recruiting11] rights to execute SP.
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo
    TO Recruiting11;
GO
```